# Is a 301 redirect the same as changing window.location?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, seo

I am a web developer who also works in SEO.
I want to 301 redirect one page to another page.
Is this 301 redirect for Google beyond what I write below for you?

In **JavaScript**:

```
<script> 
      window.location.replace("https://example.com");
</script>
```

In **PHP**:

```
<?php 
    header("Location: https://example.com");
?>
```

Are these two 301 redirects, or do we have to write `.htaccess` in the cat file, for example?

Comment: `.htaccess` is Apache httpd specific. 301 is a response status code. That's not possible with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Assigning a new location on the client side via JavaScript, has nothing to do with any redirect status codes - this isn't an _HTTP redirect_ at all. A Location header is, but `header("Location: ...` will use 302 by default, unless you explicitly specify otherwise via the third parameter. _"or do we have to write .htaccess in the cat file, for example?"_ - what is a "cat file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this with JavaScript.

**But you can use PHP as follows**

```
<?php 
    header("Location: https://example.com", TRUE, 301);
    exit;
?>
```

**Syntax header**

> `header(header, replace, http_response_code)`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the URL with `window.location` in JavaScript is not a 301 redirect.  JavaScript runs after the page has been generated on the server. Your JavaScript to change the URL would likely run on a page that has a `200 OK` status.

That being said, Google treats JavaScript redirects very similarly to 301 permanent redirects.  In most cases, Google will choose not to index the redirecting URL and pass the link juice from it to the target of the redirect.

On the other hand, clients that don't execute JavaScript won't see your JS powered redirect.  That includes other search engines like Bing, Baidu, and Yandex, as well as broken link checkers and other SEO analysis tools.

Furthermore, even to Google, 301 redirects are a much stronger signal than a JavaScript redirect. Google is most likely to honor a redirect when it is a `301 Permanent` variety compared to JS redirects, `302 Temporary` redirects, or meta refreshes.

If you have the ability and opportunity to implement server side `301 Permanent` redirects, you should do so instead of JS redirects.